# Django Template - Increment the value of a variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following code in my template

```
{% set counter = 0 %}
{% for object in object_list %}
    {% if object.attr1 == list1.attr1 and object.attr2 = list2.attr2 %}
        <li><a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}"> Link {{counter++}} </a></li>
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I setting the value of a variable using this [custom tag](http://www.soyoucode.com/2011/set-variable-django-template) and what I want to do is to increment the value only if the `if` loop is satisfied. I know `{{counter++}}` does not work. But how  can I write a custom tag that would do the same task?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Changing the state of an object in a Django template is discouraged. You should probably bite the bullet, calculate the condition beforehand and pass extra state to the template so you can simplify the template logic.

I'm no purist in this regard by the way, but I have been bitten by the purposeful limitations of Django templates a few times. You're better off not fighting against it, in my opinion.

Being that your intention seems to be to filter out non-matching items, an alternative would be to filter out those in the view and then use [`{{ forloop.counter }}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for) to sort out the link text you want. So in the view you have something like this:

```
new_lst = filter(lambda x: x.attr0 == attr0 and x.attr1 == attr1, lst)
```

And then, in your template:

```
{% for object in new_lst %}
   <li><a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}"> Link {{ forloop.counter }} </a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: +1 nice answer, [for reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for), pardon the pun

Comment: I generally do not try to circumvent the limitations of Django but this time I really needed to do that.... In my condition `{{ forloop.counter }}` does not help. I have however given my template code, can you tell if I can use `{{ forloop.counter }}`

Comment: +1 Using the forloop counter is the way to go here. @Sachin: if you want zero-based use `{{ forloop.counter0 }}`, though.

Comment: I do not understand how can I use ` {{ forloop.counter }}` when I want my `counter` value to be incremented only when the `if` condition is satisfied

Comment: To clarify: I don't think you can use `forloop.counter` to solve this. Why do you need to solve this using the template system (including tags) only? Legitimate question, I'm curious - I'm not panning your intent or anything.

Comment: There could be a use case where you have a base template that all other templates inherit from. Then you do not have a specific view that you could do this in and would have to do in the the context_processors maybe if there is no way to use the templates.

Answer (score 16):

Although this has been answered and goes against what has been said I just had a thought and can't see too much harm if perhaps you made simple counter class like

```
class Counter:
    count = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.count += 1
        return ''

    def decrement(self):
        self.count -= 1
        return ''

    def double(self):
        self.count *= 2
        return ''
```

then in your template `{{ counter.increment }}` `{{ counter.count }}` etc.

Comment: @TI: Why `count = 0` is define? `count` is instant, class or static variable?

Comment: clever solution

Comment: doesn't work in template; the increment works but {{ counter.count }} is always 0, maybe a caching or something in Dango

Answer (score 5):

For increase value in template django:
if varint=6, the result will be 8

```
{{ varint|add:"2" }}
```

For decrease value in template django:

if varint=6, the result will be 5

```
  {{ varint|add:"-1" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out the answer myself. As I said I was using [this custom tag](http://www.soyoucode.com/2011/set-variable-django-template), which assigns a value to a variable. What is actually does is set give a value to a variable in the `context` so I just retrieved the value from the context and incremented it.

Here is the code

```
class IncrementVarNode(template.Node):

    def __init__(self, var_name):
        self.var_name = var_name

    def render(self,context):
        value = context[self.var_name]
        context[self.var_name] = value + 1
        return u""

def increment_var(parser, token):

    parts = token.split_contents()
    if len(parts) < 2:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("'increment' tag must be of the form:  {% increment <var_name> %}")
    return IncrementVarNode(parts[1])

register.tag('increment', increment_var)
```

It can be used like this `{% increment <var_name> %}` but this var_name should have been set to a value previously using the custom tag mentioned above as `{% set <var_name> = <var_value> %}`

Comment: I am getting some weird behavior with this. my updates don't save in an embedded for loop, as if a secondary namespace is being copied temporarily, then erased once the for loop is gone, any ideas?