# Django template: Show a link only once if a user belongs in more than one groups

Tags: html, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have a `template` in `django` that shows a link if a user has group name different than patient.

My code is:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  {% for group in user.groups.all %}
    {% if group.name != 'Patient' %}
      <li {% if request.get_full_path == modules_url %} class="active" {% else%} class="inactive"{% endif %}>
        <a href="{% url 'modules' %}"><b  style="color:#ff9904;">Modules</b></a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

In case a user is a member of four different groups, the link `Modules` is shown 4 times in the template.

Is there any way to show it only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8659626/1395874). I used the `forloop.counter` variable.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  {% for group in user.groups.all %}
    {% if group.name != 'Patient' %}
      {% if forloop.counter < 2 %}
        <li {% if request.get_full_path == modules_url %} class="active" {% else%} class="inactive"{% endif %}>
          <a href="{% url 'modules' %}"><b  style="color:#ff9904;">Modules</b></a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think by handle using templatetags should easier.

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group 

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='has_group') 
def has_group(user, group_name):
    """
    {% if request.user|has_group:'grouName' %}
      {# do_stuff #}
    {% endif %}

    return Boolean (True/False)
    """
    group =  Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
    return group in user.groups.all()
```

Basicly you can also do with this to get *first group*:

```
{% if user.groups.all.0 == 'Patient' %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: But what about the case that the Patient group is not the first?

Comment: that's why I recommend you to use templatetags.