# How to get a certain number of elements in django template

Tags: django, templates, for-loop, if-statement

I wonder how I can get a specific number of items when i put an if statement inside a for loop

i know we can do `{% for i in items|slice ":5"%}` to get a number of items but when i do

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% for img in post_imgs %}
        {% if img.link == post.link %}
            <img class="class" src="{{img.img.url}}" style="width:100%">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

there's no way of doing that inside the if tag .. any solution

Comment: This would be better done in the views. It's a good practice to keep the business logic outside the templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659560/django-template-increment-the-value-of-a-variable):

> Changing the state of an object in a Django template is discouraged.
>   You should probably bite the bullet, calculate the condition
>   beforehand and pass extra state to the template so you can simplify
>   the template logic.

So just do your comparisons in python in your view, something like:

```
post_imgs_filtered = [img for img in post_imgs if img.link == post.link]
```

And then in your template:

```
{% for img in post_imgs_filtered|slice ":5" %}
    <img class="class" src="{{img.img.url}}" style="width:100%">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: when i do that i get an error saying  `AttributeError at /test
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'link'`

Comment: I added a for loop in the question which i forgot to put in at first

Comment: Yes you need to loop through your QuerySet before accessing its elements. This is a different python issue.

Comment: how can i add that to the post_img_filtered ?

Comment: It depends of your data structures, if `posts` and `post_imgs` are QuerySets you can use filters for example.