# How to increment a variable in a template Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

here is my views.py file in which i have delcared function

> subhead

that load account objects to view

```
def subhead(request):
    subheads=Account.objects.all()

    return render(request,'my/test.html',{'accounts':subheads})
```

here is my template

```
{% for subhead in subheads %}
         {% with i=0  %}
           {% if subhead.parent == None and subhead.type == 'As' %}
              {% if i == 0 %}

                  <tr>
                    <td>Assets</td>
                      <td>{{ subhead.name }}</td>
                  </tr>
               {% else %}
                 <tr>
                   <td></td>
                   <td>{{ subhead.name }}</td>
                 </tr>

               {% endif %}
             {% endif %}
          {% set i=i+1  %}
        {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now simply i want to increment a variable value But i don't know, how i can achieve this task.I have delcared a variable i =0 and also tried to set its values.But it returns an error

> Invalid block tag on line 419: 'set', expected 'endwith'. Did you
>   forget to register or load this tag?

And forloop.counter didn't fit in case.Because i wanted to count in if condition and wanted to show static td for once.So Please don't suggest it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659560/django-template-increment-the-value-of-a-variable

Comment: You need to explain why forloop.counter is not what you want.

Comment: Are you really looking for `forloop.counter0`?

Comment: Because i wanted to count in if condition and wanted to show static td for once. So that's i have nothing to do with forloop.counter. @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a for-loop Django itself already popluates some special [template variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for). For your example you could check `{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}` or `{% if forloop.first %}`.

Comment: Sorry dude but i don't want to use forloop.counter .