# Get Incremented count after forloop depending on condition in template django

Tags: python, django

Edits: Here is my view.py code and my template to render those lists, so how can i get that count depending on the department id on department list

**view.py**

```
def settings(request):
campuses = Campus.objects.all()
faculties = Faculty.objects.all()
departments = Department.objects.all()
programmes = Programme.objects.all()
# programme_by_department = programmes.select_related('department')
# department = Department.objects.get(pk=id)
programme_in_department = Programme.objects.values('department_id')


return render(request, 'settings.html', {'my_campus_list': campuses,
                                         'my_faculty_list': faculties,
                                         'my_department_list': departments,
                                         'my_programme_list': programmes,
                                         'programme_by_department': programme_in_department})
```

**department_list.html**

```
{% for my_programme in my_programme_list %}
<tr>
<td>
{{ forloop.counter }}
</td>
<td><small>{{ my_programme.programme_name }}</small></td>
<td><small>{{ my_programme.programme_type }}</small></td>
<td><small>{{ my_programme.department.department_name }}</small></td>

<td>

    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" type="button" class="js-update-programme"  data-url="{% url 'programme_update' my_programme.id %}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>

    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" type="button" class="js-programme-delete" data-target="#modal-programme" data-url="{% url 'programme_delete' programme_id=my_programme.id %}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

</td>
</tr>
 {% empty %}
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7" class="text-center bg-warning">No Programmes</td>
    </tr>



{% endfor %}
```

Comment: do you want total `programme_by_department`?

Comment: You can use `programme_by_department.count`

Comment: I forgot to mention there is outer for loop for department where in my inner loop i check if department_id matches

Answer (score 0):

What I'd suggest is you do `{% if my_programme_by_department.department_id == my_department.id %}` this in the `view.py` itself and then send the final queryset to the frontend. You can also pack the queryset's `length` into the context and send it. Or you can use `.count` method to get the count of it on the frontend.

An example on how this might go, *in `views.py`*

```
new_set = [ my_programme_by_department for my_programme_by_department in programme_by_department if  my_programme_by_department.department_id == my_department.id ]

new_set_length = len(new_set)
```

Now you can pack these 2 in context

```
context = {
'new_set':new_set,
'new_set_length':new_set_length 
}
```

And just render as usual in the front end using `{{ new_set_length }}`

It's always better to leave most of the logic to `views.py` instead of bringing them to templates.

Comment: So there is no way i can do it in my template, because i have a view function which render faculties, departments, programmes on on page

Comment: There are, you need create a class in views.py and pass new object for each iteration. Here's a reference for it, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8671715/6740036)