# How to declare variable in django html file. not pass from any view. and i also update that variable

Tags: python, django

I check all blogs in **stackorverflow** but i doesn't find any solution.

[Django Template - Increment the value of a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659560/django-template-increment-the-value-of-a-variable)

This link solution doesn't work. please tell me Other solution.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: Do you want your value within only one place in a template or consistent accross all templates?

Answer (score 1):

We can do something like this:

```
{% with value=0 %}
    {{ value }}
    {{ value|add:2 }}
{% endwith %}
```

---

Output:

```
0 2
```

---

You might want to read: [Built-in template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/)