# How can increment a variable value in django template language

Tags: python, django

How can I increment a variable value in django template language?

```
{% with a=0 %}
{% with b=4 %}
{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

I used above code to assign value to a variable. I want to increment it by 4.

Comment: I tried this one.. it shows error..{% set count = 1 %}
{% for i in p %}
  {{ count }}
  {% set count = count + 1 %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: is there any closing tag for set tag ?

Comment: I already tried set tag.. then i got this error..                                                                                      "TemplateSyntaxError at /workshops/
Invalid block tag on line 681: 'set', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Comment: I tried to add code inside for loop in template language.. for each iteration i want to increment value of variable by 4..

Comment: So, which template language you are using **actually**, django or jinja? As noted in [raphael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71113648/3440745) they are NOT the same. Please, [edit] your question post and clarify it.

Comment: django template language

Answer (score 2):

Jinja is similar to the Django template language, but they are not the same.  Checkout the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinja_(template_engine))

> Jinja is a web template engine for the Python programming language. It
> was created by Armin Ronacher and is licensed under a BSD License.
> Jinja is similar to the Django template engine but provides
> Python-like expressions while ensuring that the templates are
> evaluated in a sandbox. It is a text-based template language and thus
> can be used to generate any markup as well as source code.

Now to your question, the following is the correct syntax for what I think you're trying to do.  *However*, the django template is not the best place to do much math.

```html
{% with a=0 %}
  {{ a|add:'4' }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Hi.. its working.. thank you.. & here i don't want to display answer on my UI. i just want to increment its value with 4.. my work is just like a for loop in c++ that increments its value with 4 in each iteration.. is it possible in template language..

Comment: The template language *IS* for display, not for logic or math.  It is NOT C++.  Do the math and logic in your view, then pass on the results to the template.  If you really need to do this, there are some clever solutions.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659560/django-template-increment-the-value-of-a-variable.